# Angular 16: CSRF config: can I still use the HttpXsrfInterceptor and HttpXsrfCookieExtractor classes? Intelli-J says they are not existing

Tags: angular

In [this excellent article on CSRF configuration](https://www.stackhawk.com/blog/angular-csrf-protection-guide-examples-and-how-to-enable-it/) for Angular, two options are described for the CSRF config:

First: use the default Csrf config:

```
providers: [
{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useExisting: **HttpXsrfInterceptor**, multi: true }
]
```

Second: If you're using a custom interceptor, then add the following in the provider section:

```
{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: CustomInterceptor, multi: true }
{ provide: HttpXsrfTokenExtractor, useClass: **HttpXsrfCookieExtractor** }
```

The import statement is:

```
import {HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClientModule, HttpClientXsrfModule, HttpXsrfTokenExtractor} from '@angular/common/http';
```

... and of course:

```
imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ...
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpClientXsrfModule.withOptions({
      cookieName: 'X-COOKIE-CSRF-TOKEN',
      headerName: 'X-HEADER-CSRF-TOKEN'
    })
  ],
```

When working with Intelli-J, both the HttpXsrfInterceptor and HttpXsrfCookieExtractor  classes are missing. I searched for deprecation messages, but could not find them. Did I miss anything on a change in CSRF protection in Angular 16?

So, when the first option was not possible, I switched to the second option. The problem is that the HttpXsrfCookieExtractor is missing. Without configuring it, the getToken() will always result in a 'null' cookie.

How can I configure in Angular 16 (or even 15?) either the default CSRF mechanism or the custom interceptor mechanism?

Comment: The `HttpXsrfInterceptor` was never public.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use CSRF either import `HttpClientXsrfModule` or add `provideHttpClient(withXsrfConfiguration())`

Comment: @Mathieu can we do `importProvidersFrom(HttpClientXsrfModule)` in the environment providers to get all the providers as per the [docs](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClientXsrfModule)?

Comment: `withXsrfConfiguration` is not a provider list but an option to pass to `provideHttpClient()`

Comment: @mathieu sorry, I mean't `importProvidersFrom(HttpClientXsrfModule)`

Comment: You could but I don't see the purpose. Either use modules of the provider functions. I'd use the latter

Comment: Tx. Yes, I used import option but that doesn't work in Angular 16.